# South and django-allauth: how can I get all tables to be synced?

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south, django-allauth

I am trying to use django-allauth for user authentication.  FB login is not working for me  I am trouble-shooting, and wondering if it is because "allauth" tables are not synced.

However, I am unable to "migrate" the tables.  It tells me to "migrate", yet "migrate" throws an error. I'm obviously missing a trick.  Any suggestions?

```
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > storages
 > evernote
 > discover
 > hello
 > south
 > django.contrib.sites
 > djrill

Not synced (use migrations):
 - polls
 - allauth
 - allauth.account
 - allauth.socialaccount
 - allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ python manage.py migrate allauth 
Running migrations for allauth:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for allauth.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ python manage.py migrate allauth.account
? You have no migrations for the 'account' app. You might want some.
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ python manage.py schemamigration  allauth.account --auto
You cannot use --auto on an app with no migrations. Try --initial.
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ python manage.py schemamigration  allauth.account --initial
 + Added model account.EmailAddress
 + Added model account.EmailConfirmation
Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate account
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ python manage.py migrate allauth.account
Running migrations for account:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > account:0001_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "account_emailaddress" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "user_id" integer NOT NULL, "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "verified" boolean NOT NULL, "primary" boolean NOT NULL)
The error was: relation "account_emailaddress" already exists
```

So therein lies my confusion... why is it trying to CREATE TABLE if it already exists?

Based on another thread, here is pip freeze in case useful:

```
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ pip freeze
Django==1.6.5
Pillow==2.6.1
South==1.0
boto==2.32.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
django-allauth==0.18.0
django-audiotracks==0.2.4
django-storages==1.1.8
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
djrill==1.2.0
docopt==0.4.0
evernote==1.25.0
gunicorn==19.0.0
httplib2==0.9
mandrill==1.0.56
mutagen==1.22
oauth2==1.5.211
oauthlib==0.6.3
psycopg2==2.5.3
pydub==0.9.2
python-openid==2.2.5
requests==2.3.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.1
static3==0.5.1
whitenoise==1.0.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
youtube-dl==2014.09.25
```

And to confirm, despite the above loop, I am back to where I started:

```
(app01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:getstartapp macuser$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > storages
 > evernote
 > discover
 > hello
 > south
 > django.contrib.sites
 > djrill

Not synced (use migrations):
 - polls
 - allauth
 - allauth.account
 - allauth.socialaccount
 - allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

## How can I get all tables to be "synced"?

Comment: @rnevius, what do you mean? I thought I was... schemamigration etc. are from the south docs, http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#converting-existing-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. The tables that you manage with South don't have to be synced when you do a `syncdb`.

You have to manage those tables with South (basically with `schemamigration` to detect the changes on the models and create the migration file, and then with `migrate` to apply these changes to the db. I recommend you read the [tutorial of South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html) ;)

And finally, if you want to syncdb and migrate with one line you can do it like this:

```
python manage.py syncdb --migrate
```